# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object to print instagram photos

Tags: php, instagram

I am trying to print my instagram photos, but there is an error:

> **Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in...
>
> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

```
function fetchData($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN");

$result = json_decode($result);

foreach ($result->data as $post) {
     if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
         // Do Nothing
     }
     else {
            echo '<a class="instagram-unit" target="blank" href="'.$post->link.'">
            <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
            <div class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).' | '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $post->caption->created_time)).'</div></a>';
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to check in `$post`. You may be access a property that is not an object. Also check the `$result` too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the PHP version problem. After I upload online, there is no any error. On localhost, it is showing the error.